# Kali Linux inside VMWare using NAT: DNS not resolving names

Tags: linux, networking, dns, vmware

I have a Kali Linux installed in VMWare Workstation. The virtual machines is configured for using NAT. The host server is Windows 8.1.

DNS in Kali is not working:

```
$ ping -c1 www.google.es
ping: unknown host www.google.es
```

Networking is working:

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=128 time=32.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=2 ttl=128 time=25.0 ms
```

DNSs configured are Google's:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.8.9
```

Any idea?

Comment: What does `sudo dhclient -v wlan0` (substitue wlan0 for your interface) say? And `dig google.com`?

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible points of failure:

- is TCP/UDP connectivity to the DNS server working?
- is the C library configured to use DNS in the first place, and if so, using which resolver library?

The first point can be tested using any of the commands suggested before:

```
host www.google.es 8.8.8.8
nslookup www.google.es 8.8.8.8
dig +short www.google.es @8.8.8.8
```

Since the DNS server can be pinged successfully, we know IP routing works and ICMP traffic is allowed - but it tells us nothing about DNS traffic specifically, i.e. TCP and UDP traffic to port 53. A firewall could block that without blocking ICMP, or vice versa.

For the second possible point of failure, run:

```
grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

If the answer does not include keywords `dns`, `resolve` nor `lwres`, then the hostname resolution in this VM has been configured to not use DNS at all - the keywords will indicate which methods are actually going to be used.

- `dns` is the classic DNS resolver, configured via `/etc/resolv.conf`
- `lwres` is `libnss-lwres`: if you find this, also verify that a `lwresd` process is running and it has not been configured to use a custom configuration file instead of the default `/etc/resolv.conf`
- `resolve` indicates `libnss-resolve`: if you find this, verify that the `systemd-resolved` process is running, and use the `systemd-resolve --status` command to view the current DNS configuration. **In this case the classic `/etc/resolv.conf` might not necessarily be used at all,** other than to direct applications that use their own DNS resolver libraries to send their queries to `systemd-resolved`.

To test whether or not an application can successfully use whichever hostname resolution library has been configured, use `getent hosts www.google.es`. If you think the application uses IPv4 only, or specifies a preference for IPv4, you can also test with `getent ahostsv4 www.google.es`. Likewise, to test specifically for IPv6 only, you can use `getent ahostsv6 www.google.es`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use host or nslookup and force it to ask a special server

```
$ host www.google.es 8.8.8.8
$ nslookup www.google.es 8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Or,
dig www.google.es @8.8.8.8
Try other hostnames as well.

There may be needed to check if DNS port 53 is open (mostly UDP, but TCP as well )